# Error: must be character, not glue/character when using glue() inside case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the glue package to generate dynamic text in a report.  When I use `dplyr::case_when` to switch between conditions, I get an error from glue.

```
library(dplyr); library(glue)
one_car <- mtcars[10, ]

# Throws error:
answer <- case_when(
  one_car$mpg < 25 ~ glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage"),
  one_car$mpg >= 25 ~ glue(row.names(one_car), " has good mileage")  
)
```

> Error: must be character, not glue/character

The `case_when` works without glue:

```
answer <- case_when(
  one_car$mpg < 25 ~ 0,
  one_car$mpg >= 25 ~ 1  
)
```

And the glue works when run alone:

```
glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage")
#> Merc 280 has bad mileage
```

Comment: The `ifelse` is working fine.  So, it should be some env problem within `case_when` `ifelse(one_car$mpg < 25, glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage"), glue(row.names(one_car), " has good mileage"))#[1] "Merc 280 has bad mileage" .  If we check the classes `str(glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage"))#
Classes 'glue', 'character'  chr "Merc 280 has bad mileage"`. So probably wrap it with `character`

`

Comment: see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3109

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason could be the incompatibility of `glue` class within `case_when`.

```
str(glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage"))
#Classes 'glue', 'character'  chr "Merc 280 has bad mileage"
```

A quick fix is to coerce it to `character`

```
case_when(
   one_car$mpg < 25 ~ as.character(glue(row.names(one_car), " has bad mileage")),
   one_car$mpg >= 25 ~ as.character(glue(row.names(one_car), " has good mileage"))  
  )
#[1] "Merc 280 has bad mileage"
```